# Parse API json to java servlet

Tags: java, json, servlets

I'm building a java servlet page for school and I'd like to put an API inside of it. So far I've had some problems with the API.
It's the "Schiphol PublicFlight API" that I want to link to my web page.
However I can't get java to use the JSON based API.

So far I've tried to 'isolate' more and more of the JSON code, but I just can't get it to work. To make it somewhat easier for me I've separated the java servlet code from the project for now. So this is my code now:

```java
package nl.hva.ic103.johannes;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

        String flightnumber = "HV6672";
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("https://api.schiphol.nl/public-flights/flights?app_id=61439ff8&app_key=b313373fd4122e93704874c69a59233d&flightname=" + flightnumber + "&sort=%2Bscheduletime");
        request.addHeader("ResourceVersion", "v3");

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");

            System.out.println(responseBody);

            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(responseBody);
            JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) jsonObject;

            String id = (String) jo.get("id");
            String lastName = (String) jo.get("flightName");

            System.out.println(id);
            System.out.println(lastName);

            JSONArray ja = (JSONArray) jo.get("flights");

            System.out.println(ja);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the JSON format the API gives me:

```
{
    "flights": [
    {
        "id": 125936439536285950,
        "flightName": "HV6672",
        "scheduleDate": "2018-12-26",
        "flightDirection": "A",
        "flightNumber": 6672,
        "prefixIATA": "HV",
        "prefixICAO": "TRA",
        "scheduleTime": "01:00:00",
        "serviceType": "J",
        "mainFlight": "HV6672",
        "codeshares": {
            "codeshares": [
                "KL2582"
            ]
        },
        "estimatedLandingTime": "2018-12-26T00:30:49.000+01:00",
        "actualLandingTime": "2018-12-26T00:30:55.000+01:00",
        "publicEstimatedOffBlockTime": null,
        "actualOffBlockTime": null,
        "publicFlightState": {
            "flightStates": [
                "LND",
                "EXP"
            ]
        },
        "route": {
            "destinations": [
                "TFS"
            ]
        },
        "terminal": 1,
        "gate": "D74",
        "baggageClaim": {
            "belts": [
                "6"
            ]
        },
        "expectedTimeOnBelt": "2018-12-26T01:16:53.669+01:00",
        "checkinAllocations": null,
        "transferPositions": null,
        "aircraftType": {
            "iatamain": "73H",
            "iatasub": "73H"
        },
        "aircraftRegistration": "PHHZX",
        "airlineCode": 164,
        "expectedTimeGateOpen": null,
        "expectedTimeBoarding": null,
        "expectedTimeGateClosing": null,
        "schemaVersion": "3"
    }
    ],
    "schemaVersion": "3"
}
```

How can I get things like 'gate', 'terminal' and 'aircraft Type' parsed to my java program? I feel like all I can get with these results are like one piece of data and it's not possible to separate the data.
Does anyone know how to parse those three results to my java project?
More information about the API is listed on their website:
https://www.schiphol.nl/en/developer-center/page/our-flight-api-explored/

Comment: I might consider using GSON library instead, which can parse JSON into a POJO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JSONArray ja = (JSONArray) jo.get("flights");
JsonObject flightRec = ja.getJsonObject(0);
String gate = (String) flightRec.get("gate");
//...etc
```

What problem?

Comment: I'm getting a "cannot resolve method 'getJsonObject(int)'" and a "cannot cast com.google.gson.JsonElement to java.lang.String". How should I fix that then?

Comment: You use gson? Try `JsonObject rec = ja.get(0).getAsJsonObject(); String gate = rec.get("gate").getAsString();` see manual for your json library for detals (https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html)

Comment: I converted everything to Gson now and together with your code it finaly works! Thanks for your help